# sql dates as column name

Tags: sql, datetime, dynamic-sql

I want a table with columns named after dates.

example:

```
SELECT * AS GETDATE() FROM mytable;
```

From what I've read on the internet, it looks as though I will need to use dynamic SQL (?) something in the lines of this:

```
DECLARE @dt smalldatetime
SET @dt = GETDATE()
DECLARE @str varchar(100)
SET @str = 'SELECT * AS ' + convert(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 120) + ' FROM mytable'
EXEC(@str);
```

But this doesn't work. says "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: What exactly is the output format? Thanks.

Comment: Each column needs a separate alias. You can't use "SELECT * AS". So as @vamosrafa asked, what output is actually needed?

Comment: Ok, Now I've changed to "SELECT Item AS GETDATE()" and it works! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was change from SELECT * to SELECT [the thing i needed]

```
DECLARE @dt smalldatetime
SET @dt = GETDATE()
DECLARE @str varchar(100)
SET @str = 'SELECT Item AS ' + convert(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 120) + ' FROM mytable'
EXEC(@str);
```

this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dt smalldatetime

SET @dt = GETDATE()

DECLARE @str varchar(100)

SET @str = 'SELECT Item AS '+'''' + convert(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 120) +'''' + ' FROM mytable'
EXEC(@str);
```